# Share row selection between semantically different tables

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, selection, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

Let's assume, I have a list of points. One `QTableView` shows the list in Cartesian coordinates (x, y, z). Another `QTableView` shows the projection of every point to an arbitrarily chosen plane (x', y'). Now, I would like to share row selections between these two views. It should not matter, in which view the user edits the selection.

I am pretty sure that a `QAbstractProxyModel` derivative cannot be used right away, because the (x, y, z) cannot be transformed into (x', y') by simple index projections, or permutations.

**Workaround**: The two models for (x, y, z) and (x', y') are joined by a third model with (x, y, z, x', y') rows. Now, two `QSortFilterProxyModels` break up the joined columns, again. Every selection by any view is actually a selection of (x, y, z, x', y') rows, and therefore shared.

It seems clumsy, to write a whole model that joins columns, just to break them up again. However, synchronizing two selection models by connecting `currentRowChanged`, requires signal loop handling, and the `QAbstractProxyModel` interface does not to support multiple submodels. Is the workaround really the way to go? Or is there a better one?

Best regards, Marian

Additional information (edited April 2nd):

- The solution should be robust under drag and drop of rows, too.
- The solution should scale well, if I have more than two transformations. The views for the transformations can be used independently, or as I described sharing the selected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each QtableView has a Selection model. For each of the two QtableViews you can connect the signal currentChanged of the selection model to a slot change the selection of the other QtableView by setCurrentIndex. This can be done like:

```
QObject::connect(ui->tableView1->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(onCurrentChanged1(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));

QObject::connect(ui->tableView2->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(onCurrentChanged2(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));

void MyClass::onCurrentChanged1(QModelIndex curIndex, QModelIndex prevIndex)
{
    int newRow = curIndex.row();
    int curRow = ui->tabaleView2->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row();
    if( newRow != curRow )
    {
        QModelIndex newIndex = ui->tabaleView2->model()->index(row, 0);
        ui->tabaleView2->setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    }
}
void MyClass::onCurrentChanged2(QModelIndex curIndex, QModelIndex prevIndex)
{
    int newRow = curIndex.row();
    int curRow = ui->tabaleView1->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row();
    if( newRow != curRow )
    {
        QModelIndex newIndex = ui->tabaleView1->model()->index(row, 0);
        ui->tabaleView1->setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that MyClass is some kind of _selection merging_ class. The problem with this approach is that it does not scale very well, if you select more than one row, or if you have more than two views. My idea with the proxy models was inspired by [Steveire's blog](http://steveire.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/sharing-a-qitemselection-between-views-through-proxy-models/). I get the feeling that I will have to choose the lesser of two evils.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that sharing selections is not well-defined. Selections contain a focused element. Since the columns of both tables are not comparable, there is no clear rational, which element should be focused. This answer is straight forward. It has its issues. But from ill-defined problems only workaround solutions can come. From all workarounds, this seems to be a good one.